# urllib2 httplib.BadStatusLine

Tags: python, http

I am using with python urllib2 to a connect HTTP server. Sometimes I get the response: `httplib.BadStatusLine: ''`.

My code :

```
response = None
try:
    request = urllib2.Request(http_url,params)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request,timeout=5000)
    return str(response.read())
except urllib2.HTTPError :
    return ""
except urllib2.URLError:
        return ""
```

response error :

```
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1244, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1217, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1051, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 415, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 379, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine: ''
```

I don't to know how to fix this bug? And I don't to know why I get an error response.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I removed the "snippets" as they are not JavaScript, but python code and left them as code blocks - please see [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting. I helped you with the English and made it a bit more clear. You should probably add the bit of code that defines `http_url`, as that is where your problem is. Good luck!